# Build ES6 template literal with function

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains template literal variables but is not a template literal due to it being built dynamically. I'd like to convert it into a template "literal" without doing an `eval()`:

```
   // this is dynamically created by an algo:
   const vars = '${var1} ${var2}';
   const str = 'the result is ' + vars;

   // this works, but it's nasty: 
   eval('result = `' + str + '`');
```

I'm looking for access to the internal template builder in the spirit of the RegExp class, which can be used in place of standard regexp literal slashes `//`:

```
   const myRegex = '^(\d+)$';
   new RegExp(myRegex);
```

So that way I could do:

```
   const myStr = 'I want to be ${foo}';
   const foo = 99;
   const lit = new TemplateLiteral(myStr);
   console.log( lit.run() ); // I want to be 99
```

Comment: One way could be to use a tokenizer like https://github.com/fuckingdigital/textator

Comment: It would help answer this question better if we knew more about this "dynamic creation" of the template.

Comment: If you're familiar with old-school `sprintf` or any of it's modern descendants, then [this lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprintf-js) might work better for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "build a literal". It is a contradiction in terms. A literal is a syntax in source code that compiles to a value.

`new RegExp(...)` builds a new regexp object, but not a regexp literal. RegExp literal is when you literally write `/.../`.

In the same way, string literal is literally only when you write `'...'`, `"..."` or `` `...` `` in code. You can build a *string* - typically using concatenation - but there is no way to build a string *literal*.

EDIT: Quick and dirty:

```js
function makeTemplate(template) {
  return new Function("return `" + template + "`");
}

const myStr = 'I want to be ${foo}';
const foo = 99;
const template = makeTemplate(myStr);
console.log(template());
// I want to be 99
```

However, while `new Function` is always better than `eval`, the usual disclaimers about executing untrusted strings apply.

For a safer alternative, see [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) or [Pug.js](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) (not Pod as I said in comment, sorry), as the leading JavaScript template libraries.

Comment: You're right, I'm asking for a template object not literal, just like a `RegExp` object. Once I build the template object I'll call `run()`. I'll edit the question for clarity.

Comment: A template string literal evaluates to a string, not a template. There is no such thing in JavaScript as "template object", except ones created by a library like Mustache.js or Pod.js.

Comment: @ojosilva - JavaScript doesn't have template objects. It has functions. The result of evaluating an untagged template literal is a string (the result of evaluating a tagged template literal is whatever the tag function defines).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed. I see tagged template literals so rarely my mind usually skips over them. :)

Answer (score 1):

The key issue here is what you have in your comment in the first code block:

> this is dynamically created by an algo

If the *template* is created by an algorithm, your choices are:

- Don't use the built-in template feature, use any of several similar templating libraries (or write your own)
- Use `eval` or one of its cousins (`new Function` is probably best)

You can't create template literals dynamically. They're literals. :-)

If we knew more about your algorithm, we might be able to help you better. For instance, you might be able to have the algorithm create a function, and then call that function with the information it may need:

```
function getVarsFormatter(var1First) {
    if (var1First) {
        return (var1, var2) => `${var1} ${var2}`;
    } else {
        return (var1, var2) => `${var2} ${var1}`;
    }
}
```

then

```
const formatter = getVarsFormatter(flag);
const result = formatter("this is var1", "this is var2");
```

Live Example:

```js
function getVarsFormatter(var1First) {
    if (var1First) {
        return (var1, var2) => `${var1} ${var2}`;
    } else {
        return (var1, var2) => `${var2} ${var1}`;
    }
}

for (let n = 0; n < 6; ++n) {
  const formatter = getVarsFormatter(Math.random() < 0.5);
  const result = formatter("this is var1", "this is var2");
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: The "algo" is loading the template strings from a file internal to the app.

Comment: @ojosilva - Ugh. I'm afraid if the starting point is a string defining the template (e.g., loaded from a file), your only options are the two I listed above: Use a templating library, or use `eval`'s cousin `new Function`.

Comment: @ojosilva - You said a file **internal** to the app. Could it be a JavaScript file instead, providing functions (like the ones that `getVarsFormatter` above returns)?